# How to set specific fragment to only Dark theme while rest of the app is DayNight?

Tags: android, styles, android-dark-theme

In my app I have one fragment where I need to use colors **only from dark theme pallet**.

My base AppTheme is extending from `DayNight` and I have `colors.xml` in both `values` and `values-night` folder with different hex colors for light and dark themes.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/surfacePrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/surfacePrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/surfacePrimary</item>
        ...
</style>
```

In this [article from Chris Banes](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94) I found out that `DayNight` is basicaly

```
in values:
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

and in values-night:
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight" parent="Theme.AppCompat" />
```

I tried to create a separate AppTheme that doesn't extend from DayNight with hope that this theme will use colors from `values-night` folder.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/surfacePrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/surfacePrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/surfacePrimary</item>
        ...
</style>
```

As you can see color attributes still points to the same colors in both themes but those colors have different hex in `values/colors.xml` and `values-night/colors.xml`. Then applied Dark theme in `onCreateView` of needed fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    activity?.theme?.applyStyle(R.style.AppTheme_Dark, true)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false)
}
```

But this did not work out. I know that I could add separate independent colors just for this fragment and set their hex to be always equal to one in dark mode. But I would really like to avoid it and use already existing colors I have.

How can I force `AppTheme.Dark` to use colors from `values-night/colors.xml`?